# How can I cast a pointer of type size_t to a pointer of enum ?

Tags: c++, pointers

I want to assign a size_t to this container :

```
  std::vector <nts::Tristate *>   _components;
```

To do so, I am trying to cast `const size_t &` to `nts::Tristate *`

```
this->_components[0] = static_cast<nts::Tristate *>(&value);
```

But I have the following error :

```
error: invalid static_cast from type ‘const size_t* {aka const long unsigned int*}’ to type ‘nts::Tristate*’
     this->_components[0] = static_cast<nts::Tristate *>(&value);
```

Have any idea why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without asking *why* you want to do something like that, the problem is that the two types (`size_t*` and `nts::Tristate*`) are completely unrelated, and you need to *reinterpet* one type as the other. You do thing with [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

It should be noted that doing something like this will most likely lead to other problems down the road, problems that will lead to *undefined behavior*. One of the things you need to watch out for is if `value` is a local variable, because then you store a pointer to this local variable that will go out of scope and disappear. Another is that the rest of the program that uses `_components[0]` needs to know that it's not actually a pointer to a `nts::Tristate` object but a pointer to a `size_t` value. In short, what you're doing is very dangerous.